# Format data from database to Highcharts series Format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I have data which comes from database

```
var data = [{
    "plants_ref_id": "1",
    "plant_name": "MCW",
    "employees_data": "1,1,21,21"
}, {
    "plants_ref_id": "2",
    "plant_name": "VGU",
    "employees_data": "2,3,12,12"
}];
```

and a static array

```
 var incidents = ['Near miss', 'High Potential Near miss', 'First-aid cases', 'LTI'];
```

I am trying to convert this data to a specific format for displaying Highcharts as [**https://jsfiddle.net/94uvmL95/1/**](https://jsfiddle.net/94uvmL95/1/)

I have given series manually in the above fiddle link.

How do I generate series with the variables **data** and **incidents**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function

```
function like_add(data){
    var Nearmiss=[];
    var HighPotential=[];
    var FirstAid=[];
    var LTI=[];
    $.each(data,function () {
        var values=this.employees_data.split(',');
            Nearmiss.push(parseInt(values[0]));
            HighPotential.push(parseInt(values[1]));
            FirstAid.push(parseInt(values[2]));
            LTI.push(parseInt(values[3]));
    });
    var incidents = [Nearmiss, HighPotential, FirstAid,LTI];
    return incidents;
}
var data =[{"plants_ref_id":"1","plant_name":"MCW","employees_data":"1,1,21,21"},{"plants_ref_id":"2","plant_name":"VGU","employees_data":"2,3,12,12"}];
var incidents=like_add(data);
alert(incidents.toSource());
```

Just check here [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/94uvmL95/4/)

Comment: The Fiddle you posted is giving giving output to variable incidents. If I pass the variable to series there is no graph displaying https://jsfiddle.net/94uvmL95/3/

Comment: I just forget to parseInt now try this https://jsfiddle.net/94uvmL95/4/